# How to customize Microsoft Graph client using OkHttpClient

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, okhttp

Im using client credential approach to fetch data using Microsoft Graph api.
As mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=java), we can customize it.

However im unable to understand how to create coreAuthenticationProvider.

Any code snippet to explain the cuztomization will be helpful.

Below is the code snippet i tried:

```
    final ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(this.clientId, this.scopes,
            this.clientSecret, this.tenantId, NationalCloud.Global);

    final OkHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(authProvider).newBuilder()
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false).build();

    final IHttpProvider httpProvider = DefaultClientConfig.createWithAuthenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .getHttpProvider(httpClient);

    final IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .httpProvider(httpProvider).buildClient();
```

However i endup getting below errors:

```
2021-03-12T22:10:39,340 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
2021-03-12T22:10:39,340 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
2021-03-12T22:10:39,340 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2021-03-12T22:10:39,341 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?%24select=Id%2CDisplayName%2CMail%2CUserPrincipalName%2CEmployeeId&%24expand=registeredDevices
2021-03-12T22:10:39,341 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.6.0
2021-03-12T22:10:39,341 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
2021-03-12T22:10:39,341 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2021-03-12T22:10:39,342 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2021-03-12T22:10:39,342 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220401 : Unauthorized
2021-03-12T22:10:39,342 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[...]
2021-03-12T22:10:39,342 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
2021-03-12T22:10:39,343 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
2021-03-12T22:10:39,343 ERROR [restartedMain] c.m.g.l.DefaultLogger: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?%24select=Id%2CDisplayName%2CMail%2CUserPrincipalName%2CEmployeeId&%24expand=registeredDevices
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.6.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


401 : Unauthorized
[...]
```

If i remove the client customization code it works. Below code is working:

```
final ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(this.clientId, this.scopes,
        this.clientSecret, this.tenantId, NationalCloud.Global);

final IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .buildClient();

return graphClient;
```

Below is the OKHttp Logging Interceptor (Level : Header) for the failure scenario (I have truncated the access token)

```
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: SdkVersion: graph-java/v2.10.0
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Authorization: Bearer eyc19PUm5Cei1qUFBZdzZ0Y2REeWJjcW9zdlhPeTktVnVvdWhrZ0kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZC    Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Accept: */*
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: SdkVersion: graph-java-core/v1.0.9 (featureUsage=0), java/1.8.0_66
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: client-request-id: afbfefac-a85e-4b1b-8133-cf4599b502f6
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Authorization: Bearer ec19PUm5Cei1qUFBZdzZ0Y2REeWJjcW9zdlhPeTktVnVvdWhrZ0kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZC    Mar 14, 2021 6:50:45 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> END GET
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- 401 Unauthorized https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users (2794ms)
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Date: Sun, 14 Mar 2021 13:20:47 GMT
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Content-Type: application/json
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Vary: Accept-Encoding
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: request-id: bfdaf163-7429-416f-a139-208934180ef2
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: client-request-id: afbfefac-a85e-4b1b-8133-cf4599b502f6
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Korea Central","Slice":"E","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"SE1PEPF00000918"}}
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Connection: Keep-Alive
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: Proxy-support: Session-based-authentication
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:47 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- END HTTP
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220401 : Unauthorized
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[...]
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 220[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
Mar 14, 2021 6:50:48 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.10.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


401 : Unauthorized
[...]
```

(The same access token works if tested manually using Postman)

**But i need a way to Customize the Microsoft Graph SDK service client **

Comment: You should debug and compare the two clients that get created.  From your example it isn't possible to reproduce.

Comment: Also look at headers that are sent https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: I have added the interceptor and set the logging level to HEADERS but nothing is seen on the console?

Comment: You are probably going to need to debug the running program. Step through it. I can't help from this.

Comment: I have updated the logging info

Comment: I'd be careful about publicly posting bearer tokens. I was trying to give you a way to compare the two requests. Ultimately you'll need to understand the difference yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to set the OkHttpClient,

```
final ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(this.clientId, this.scopes,
            this.clientSecret, this.tenantId, NationalCloud.Global);

final OkHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(new ICoreAuthenticationProvider() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticateRequest(final Request request) {
                return request;
            }
        }).newBuilder().retryOnConnectionFailure(false).build();



final IHttpProvider httpProvider = DefaultClientConfig.createWithAuthenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .getHttpProvider(httpClient);

final IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .httpProvider(httpProvider).buildClient();
```